# Can "rage about" be used in a positive sense?

Tags: meaning

> What's all the rage about/around Euphoria? The show just promotes drugs.

Here, I want to use the word "rage around" in the sense of "hype around". Is it correct?

Comment: *rage* is closely connected with **anger, violence, aggression, uncontrollable emotion**, *hype* - with **extravagance, intensity, exaggeration**. Both of them are rarely meant positively.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes. I just read about the informal phrase "all the rage" and thought if I could use rage like this.

Comment: [When something is popular and fashionable, you can say that it is the rage or all the rage.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rage) - I didn't know this meaning, and it seems to be old-fashioned

Comment: No. There is no idiom of "rage around".

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - Oddly enough, ["all the rage" seemed to be on the decline for 200 years, and then in the 1980s started regaining favor.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+the+rage&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20the%20rage%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "All the rage" to mean something is very popular is very natural to my Canadian ears, though maybe a decade or two out of date now. "Gone viral" has replaced it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. "All the rage" is a set phrase and it is always used more like an attribute of a thing (like "purple"). So it is somewhat awkward here. Certainly "the rage" as an informal idiom to mean "popular" exists, but in your example the listener would probably need to adjust their assumptions about meaning when they get to the conclusion.

A more natural way of saying this might be "What's with all the hype surrounding *Euphoria*?"

"All the hype" ("all the X") is *not* a set phrase or singular noun in the way that "all the rage" is.